# How remove value from session Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, session

I have code:

```
    public function addToCompare(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'productId' => 'required|integer',
        'type' => 'required|string'
    ]);

    if ($request->type == 'add') {
        if(!session($request->productId)) 
        session(['productToCompareId' => $request->productId]);
        return response()->json(['success' => 'Product added to compare List!']);
    } else {
        session()->forget('productToCompareId');
        return response()->json(['success' => 'Product removed from compare List!']);
    }

    return response()->json(['error' => true]);
}
```

I need remove only one product from compared List, but my code remove all products. How I can remove only one product?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You  can achieve by doing this,

```
session(['productToCompareId' => '']);
```

There is one more way,

```
session()->forget('productToCompareId');
session()->flush();
```

Or you can do like this,

```
Session::pull('productToCompareId'); // reset current value
```

You can get more details from [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/session#deleting-data).

Comment: But how remove product with specific id?

Comment: can you give me for e.g.? I mean, what will come in place of `productToCompareId`?

Answer (score 0):

you can user

```
$request->session()->forget('key');
```

refer to the docs

[laravel Session](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/session#deleting-data)

Answer (score 0):

You can remove a single key from session array like this.

```
$request->session()->forget('key');

// or use global helper
session()->forget('key');
```

[laravel Session Deleting data](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/session#deleting-data)

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/remove-array-element-from-session?page=1